# How to manipulate smart art using vba in excel 2007?

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I am trying to create smartart org charts using excel 2007 vba.
I tried to first record the macro to see what objects are involved but with no luck. Nothing was recorded. There are some examples online of smart art and vba in excel 2010 but nothing for excel 2007. Does it mean that smart art is not accessible using vba in excel 2007? Is there maybe some workaround?

Comment: Excel 2007 doesn't record a lot of drawing layer elements, including SmartArt. In Excel2010 I'm able to record only the code line which places smartart element in the sheet. I've never worked with them by VBA but I see there is `SmartArt Object` with some properties- hopefully to manipulate them. You could place some picture here of what you need to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but is not a simple task.

Read more on

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg583880(v=office.14).aspx

You need manipulate a XML part of file to create new options of SmartArts.

For me, very big work to very small results...